# Is there an annotations plugin/helper/addon for Eclipse PDT to help with Doctrine 2 annotations mapping?

Tags: annotations, eclipse-cdt, doctrine-orm

Doctrine 2 allows to map the schema of the db by using annotations, a-la phpdoc style.
Is there any known existing eclipse addon that adds all the possible annotation options for autocompletion in eclipse pdt ?

Comment: Ohh that would be great ! Great question.

Answer (score 5):

> Just an addendum, since I posted this answer, I've switched to PhpStorm, which now has [support for Doctrine Annotations](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/12/phpstorm-7-1-eap-133-214/), using a [plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7320?pr=phpStorm) that parses the Annotation classes directly so there is no need to add the annotations manually.

---

I don't know an addon, but I know a way to add new types of docblocks.

For this do the following:
Open Eclipse PDT, go to the preferences dialog (windows -> preferences), and open the PHP templates section, see the image:

[image: Eclipse Template Creation]

Click in *New*, then change the context do *phpcomment*, and add your code. To add variables just use the *${}* wrapper.

Example of the Column annotation:

```
name: @Column
Pattern: @Column(name="${name}", type="${type}")
```

If someone does this for all annotations of Doctrine2 and want to share it with us would be very welcome. :)

Comment: good answer. SHould be marked as Accepted